# CUDA Kernel Optimization regarding register

Tags: optimization, cuda

I'm quite new to CUDA and GPU programming. I'm trying to write a Kernel for an application in physics. The parallelization is made over a quadrature of directions, each direction resulting in a sweep of a 2D cartesian domain. Here is the kernel. it actually works well, giving good results.

However, a very high number of registers per blocks leads to a spill to local memory that harshly slow down the code performance.

```
__global__ void KERNEL (int imax, int jmax, int mmax, int lg, int lgmax, 
                        double *x,   double *y, double *qd, double *kappa,
                        double *S, double *G, double *qw, double *SkG, 
                        double *Ska,double *a, double *Ljm, int *data)

{
int m   = 1+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x ; 
int tid = threadIdx.x ;

//Var needed for thread execution
...

extern __shared__ double shared[] ;

//Read some data from Global mem
mu  = qd[        (m-1)];
eta = qd[  MSIZE+(m-1)];
wm  = qd[3*MSIZE+(m-1)];
amu = fabs(mu);
aeta= fabs(eta);
ista = data[        (m-1)] ;
iend = data[1*MSIZE+(m-1)] ;
istp = data[2*MSIZE+(m-1)] ;
jsta = data[3*MSIZE+(m-1)] ;
jend = data[4*MSIZE+(m-1)] ;
jstp = data[5*MSIZE+(m-1)] ;

j1 = (1-jstp)   ;
j2 = (1+jstp)/2 ;
i1 = (1-istp)   ;
i2 = (1+istp)/2 ;

isw = ista-istp ;
jsw = jsta-jstp ;

dy = dx = 1.0e-2 ;

for(i=1 ; i<=imax; i++) Ljm[MSIZE*(i-1)+m] = S[jsw*(imax+2)+i] ;

//Beginning of the vertical Sweep, can be from left to right, 
// or opposite depending on the thread

for(j=jsta ; j1*jend + j2*j<=j2*jend + j1*j ; j=j+jstp) {

Lw = S[j*(imax+2)+isw] ;

//Beginning of the horizontal Sweep, can be from left to right, 
// or opposite depending on the thread

   for(i=ista ; i1*iend + i2*i<=i2*iend + i1*i ; i=i+istp) {

            ax = dy ;
            Lx = ax*amu/ex ;
            ay = dx ;
            Ly = ay*aeta/ey ;

            dv = ax*ay ;
            L0 = dv*kappaij ;
            Sp = S[j*(imax+2)+i]*dv ;
            Ls = Ljm[MSIZE*(i-1)+m] ;

            Lp = (Lx*Lw+Ly*Ls+Sp)/(Lx+Ly+L0) ;

            Lw = Lw+(Lp-Lw)/ex ;
            Ls = Ls+(Lp-Ls)/ey ;

            Ljm[MSIZE*(i-1)+m] = Ls ;

            shared[tid] = wm*Lp ;
            __syncthreads();

            for (s=16; s>0; s>>=1) {
                if (tid < s) {
                   shared[tid] += shared[tid + s] ;
                }
            }

            if(tid==0) atomicAdd(&SkG[imax*(j-1)+(i-1)],shared[tid]*kappaij);

    }
    // End of horizontal sweep
 }
 // End of vertical sweep
```

}

How can i optimize the execution of this code ? I run it over 8 blocks of 32 threads.
The occupancy for this kernel is really low, limited by the registers according to the Visual profiler.

I have no idea on how to improve it.

Thanks !

Comment: Don't worry too much about occupancy (either theoretical or achieved). It can be misleading as an indicator of which performance you're getting. Rather, check values from the profiler such as Instructions Per Clock (IPC) and Transactions Per Request.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using blocks of 32 threads, because of that, occupancy kernel is too low. Your gpu is running only 256 threads in parallel but it can run up to 1536 threads per multiprocessor (compute capability 2.x)

How many registers are you using?
You also can try to declare your variables into their local scope, helping to the device to reuse better the registers.

Comment: Right, I was aware that 32 threads per block was too few. With the 3D version I will run 16 block of 32 threads.

I'm using 63 register. When compiling I got the following information : 56 bytes stack frame, 64 bytes spill stores, 56 bytes spill loads.
Used 63 register, 256+0 smem